# How to update couchdb document without losing existing attachment

Tags: couchdb, attachment, ektorp

I want to update a field in couchdb document which already has an attachment.
If I update new field with the current revision then the attachment gets deleted. Is there a way so that I update the field without losing the attachment? I am using Ektorp API to update the document.

Regards
Sunil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you `GET` a document that has an attachment it will include the attachment's "stub":

```json
{
  "_id":"attachment_doc",
  "_rev":1589456116,
  "_attachments":
  {
    "foo.txt":
    {
      "stub":true,
      "content_type":"text\/plain",
      "length":29
    }
  }
}
```

When you want to update the document (e.g. through `PUT`) you must include the "stub", otherwise Couch will remove the attachment.

Edit:
I missed that you were using Erktop.

The simplest way to preserve attachment stubs then should be for your domain classes to extend `CouchDbDocument`.

If for some reason you can't do that, you need to ensure the stubs are (de)serialized. You can use the implementation from [here](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp/blob/master/org.ektorp/src/main/java/org/ektorp/support/CouchDbDocument.java).

Comment: If I copy the "_attachments" property do I need to update the "no_attachments" column also or is that just to show when attachments where attached?